# Sort a column with a particular value up top in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, ssms

I have a column `Name`. I need to show `Default Deliverable Submission Notification` at the top of my sorted table and followed by Almoda, profile update etc. How can I sort it in SQL Server.

```
ID      |    Name
-------------------
253     |    Almoda
2607    |    Default Deliverable Submission Notification
44      |    profile update
2609    |    Single Submitted Deliverable
3608    |    Single Unsubmitted Deliverable
45      |    Test for all Deliverables
```

This is the query I used

```
select *
from tblrepos
order by Name
```

Comment: What is your condition for sorting ?

Comment: You need to explain what logic a computer is supposed to follow to determine the order. Is "Default.." the only thing that should be outside the normal lexicographic order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case expression` to artificially put a specific result first in the resultset e.g.

```
select *
from tblrepos
order by
  case when [Name] = 'Default Deliverable Submission Notification' then 1 else 0 end desc
  , [Name]
```

Comment: Never realized this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate sort order column since sorting on Name is not going to help you get the item you mentioned on top. It will be lexicographically sorted by default.

Add an alternate_sort_order column to your table, assign each row a value for the position you want it to have after sorting, then use this query to get the results.

```
select id, name
from tblrepos 
order by alternate_sort_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN NAME = 'Default Deliverable Submission Notification' THEN '0' ELSE [NAME] END) AS IDA
        , *
    FROM tblrepos 
) A ORDER BY IDA
```